# Assign file to variable in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

//I want to assign a file from drawable folder to a variable:

```
 f = File("drawable/" + R.drawable.fileName)
```

//this is not working, i get back:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: drawable/2131230901: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or 
directory)
```

Comment: Resources are files on your development machine. They are not files on the device. If you explain what you are trying to accomplish, we might be able to provide some specific alternatives.

Comment: Ok i understand, in my app you can select a file/picture with picker. This file is uploaded to the server. But if someone does not select a file i want a standard/pre defined file for the upload. This file is in @drawablef folder.